# Angularjs Grid image Upload and Previews

Tags: angularjs, grid

I want to  Upload image file before upload i want to show preview of image, but i found issue like i am trying to upload image it is changing only in first grid view.

i want 
If someone can point me in the right direction, than would be great! Thanks!

I am using Code like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
  });

  function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
  };

<div ng-repeat 1 to 4>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-4-custom">
                       <img id="myImg" src="http://imagepath" width=600px height=250px class="img-full" alt="Image not found" >

 </div>

<label type='file' for="file-input1" id="file-input1" ng-file-select ng-model="files">
</div>
```